# Google ndb datastore new composite index issue

Tags: app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore

We tried adding a new composite index to an existing entity but the old data present are not indexed as expected.

We worked around the issue by reading all the data and re writing them to the datastore. After that, data are indexed and are available for querying.

Just curious, is this temporary issue at google end or it's a know limitation with ndb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. When using Google Cloud Datastore you have to know ahead of time what your queries will be in order to avoid having to read all the entities from your kind and writing them again. From time to time I end up having to do that myself as well for your use case or to add or remove a new property.

This answer explains everything about indexing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35744783/190908

There was a bug that affected composite index. It required you to index every individual property in the composite index, but since the pricing model changed, this won't end up costing you more nowadays: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4231